# Tensorflow lite example with custom model - "input_product_scale < output_scale was not true"

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

**How to reproduce:**
retrain a mobilenet with command:

```
python tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py 
—image_dir (data-pwd) 
—learning_rate=0.001 —testing_percentage=20 
—validation_percentage=20 —train_batch_size=32 
—validation_batch_size=-1 —flip_left_right True 
—random_scale=30 —random_brightness=30 
—eval_step_interval=100 —how_many_training_steps=200 
—architecture mobilenet_1.0_224_quantized —default_ranges_min=0 
—default_ranges_max=6 —std_values=224 
—mean_values=224
```

`mean values` and `std_values` don't really make a difference - tried different combinations.
then I converted the resulting .pb file like so:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco --input_file=(path)/output_graph.pb --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF 
--output_format=TFLITE 
--output_file=./mobilenet_quantized_224.tflite --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 
--input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 --input_array=Placeholder --output_array=final_result 
--input_shape=1,224,224,3
--output_array=final_result --input_shape=1,224,224,3
```

Then I've replaced in both stock apps: iOS simple and Android camera example app the tflite model with the generated one. This leads both to the same error:

**Error:**
Android:

```
Can not allocate memory for the given inputs: 
tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/kernel_util.cc:34 
input_product_scale < output_scale was not true.
```

iOS:

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/10888914-22EB-4CA7-B019-F95D5A8A6F5C/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

nnapi error: unable to open library libneuralnetworks.so
Loaded model resolved reportertensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels
/kernel_util.cc:34 input_product_scale < output_scale was not 
true.Failed to allocate tensors!(lldb)
```

**Question:**
How to solve... error? :)

**Edit as I'm adding a bounty:**
The goal would be to get an explanation on how to retrain a model and get it running with tensorflow lite. I'm aware this is very new, but I'm running left and right into errors with the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following not work for you?

<strike>bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco --input_file=(path)/output_graph.pb --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE --output_file=./mobilenet_quantized_224.tflite --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 --input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 --input_array=Placeholder --output_array=final_result --input_shape=1,224,224,3 --mean_values=128 --std_values=128 --default_ranges_min=0 --default_ranges_max=6</strike>

**I've reproduced the error you are seeing and was able to get it to work with the following commands:**

```
python tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
  --image_dir /tmp/flower_photos \
  --learning_rate=0.001 \
  --testing_percentage=20 \
  --validation_percentage=20 \
  --train_batch_size=32 \
  --validation_batch_size=-1 \
  --flip_left_right True \
  --random_scale=30 \
  --random_brightness=30 \
  --eval_step_interval=100 \
  --how_many_training_steps=200 \
  --architecture mobilenet_1.0_224_quantized
```

and

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco \
  --input_file=/tmp/output_graph.pb \
  --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --output_file=/tmp/mobilenet_quantized_224.tflite \
  --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --input_array=Placeholder \
  --output_array=final_result \
  --input_shape=1,224,224,3 \
  --mean_value=128 \
  --std_value=128 \
  --default_ranges_min=0 \
  --default_ranges_max=6
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: unfortunately not - as described I still get the error